# Reference Error on line 11: foundNum is not defined for...in loop JavaScript

Tags: javascript, for-in-loop

I have the following object called checkObj. I'm trying to use a for... in loop to see if the object contains the property foundNum. Since it does exist, the purpose of the program is to then reassign the value of "found" to 1 as shown below.

```
    const checkObj = {
      oddNum: 1,
      evenNum: 2,
      foundNum: 5,
      randomNum: 18
    };
    
    let found = 0;
    // ADD CODE HERE
    
    for (foundNum in checkObj) {
      if (object.key(checkObj).includes = foundNum ) {
        let found = 1
      }
    }
```

However, I get the following error: Reference Error on line 11: foundNum is not defined. I'm not very familiar with for... in loops so not sure how to fix this bug.

Comment: 1) You are missing a `let` in `let foundNum in checkObj`. 2) You are redeclaring `let found = 1` Remove `let` here. 3)  `includes` is a function. You don't need a loop here. You can just do: `checkObj.hasOwnProperty("foundNum")` or `"foundNum" in checkObj`

Comment: Object - with capital O, keys - plural - with s...

Comment: What happened to javascript?!?  I will NEVER use `const` NOR `let` - ONLY `var`.

Comment: These suggestions worked. Thanks!